# Title on DetailViewController

Tags: ios, title

I created a NavigationBar and DetailView, but when I select a row on the tableView, the title of the DetailView is not set.  How do I set it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you use view controllers correctly in `UINavigationController`s, then you simply need to set the title of the view:

```
self.title = @"Title";
```

By the sounds of it, you've manually placed the navigation bar in a view, which means you'll need to get a hold of the instance, and change the text in it yourself.

```
// Set a "tag" to the Navigation Bar, in Interface Builder or via code (navigationBat.tag = 200;)
UINavigationBar* bar = [self.view viewWithTag:200];
bar.title = @"Title";
```

In order to do this at the correct place, you'll need to do it on the selection of a table view row. You need to be set as the delegate for the table view.

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    self.title = @"Title"; // Or whatever mode you're using to set the title
}
```

Comment: @Avirok If this was suitable for your needs, can you please accept the answer? Thank you